# mysql select case not working with function

Tags: mysql, mysql-function

how to store value in image1 variable

```
BEGIN
DECLARE image1 VARCHAR(250);
select case when (
            (
                select COUNT(*)
                from profile_images
                where building_id = bid
                    and contractor_id = cid
                ) > 0
            ) then (
                select distinct (image)
                into image1
                from profile_images
                where building_id = bid
                    and contractor_id = cid limit 1
                ) else (
            select distinct (image)
            into image1
            from profile_images
            where contractor_id = cid limit 1
            )

END
RETURN image1;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
BEGIN
DECLARE image1 VARCHAR(250);
select case when
            (
                select COUNT(*)
                from profile_images
                where building_id = bid
                    and contractor_id = cid
                ) > 0
              then (
                select distinct (image)
                -- into image1
                from profile_images
                where building_id = bid
                    and contractor_id = cid limit 1
                ) else (
            select distinct (image)
            -- into image1
            from profile_images
            where contractor_id = cid limit 1
            )
END into image1;
RETURN image1;
END
```

Comment: The answer is useful

Comment: its working under local sever but main server ishows error with message  "#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"     @wchiquito

Comment: @samjadps: Check [B.5.2.14 Commands out of sync](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commands-out-of-sync.html).